# Firebase query with React Native not showing on my screen (but showing on console.log)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

My data is showing on console.log as intended but not on my screen.
Here's a screenshot of the console log.

[image]

And here's my code:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
this.getData();
}

getData(){
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/`)
    .orderByKey()
    .on('child_added', snap =>  {

      //Is this correct or does it need to be formatted a different way?
      snap.key, 
      snap.val().Weight 

      //note that the console logs below displays the data
      console.log(snap.key)
      console.log(snap.val().Weight)

    }) 
}

renderRow = () => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.card, styles.cardBorderTop]}>
      <Text>
        {snap.key} //Is this the correct way to reference this value?
      </Text>
      <Text style={[styles.textRight]}>
        {snap.val().Weight} //Is this the correct way to reference this value?
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.getData} //Is this the correct data reference?
          renderItem={this.renderRow} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is how my screen is rendering. Note that I'm expecting the data to render on a FlatList.
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

On a side note, I now realize that I need to store the dates as ISO-8601, so they can be sorted properly, which I'll be doing after I figure out how to get the query data to render on my screen.

**UPDATE**
I realize that my question is not as clear as I had intended and I apologize for that. What I need is to be able to query my data by the **date key** and the **Weight child**. I'm able to successfully do that using snap.key and snap.val().Weight on the console, however it doesn't look like that's the correct reference needed to display the data on my FlatList and that's what I need help with.

For reference, here's my Firebase database:
[image]

Comment: What's wrong about the way the data is displayed?

Comment: On the console log is fine but It's not displaying on my screen using FlatList. I updated the original post to include my blank screen. I'm missing something on my code. Take a look at the renderRow function and at the FlatList data reference.  Something is not right.

Comment: I'm honestly not really sure what this is supposed to do: `{
      snap.key,
      snap.val().Weight
      console.log(snap.key +  snap.val().Weight + 'LBS')
    }`. What is this supposed to return to the caller? And how do you think your caller is using it here `data={this.getData}`?

Comment: snap.key returns my key as intended in the console log. For example:  
FRI NOV 16 2018  
MON NOV 12 2018  
etc...  
and snap.val().Weight also returns the Weight child data as intended. For example:
175
171

However, it doesn't look like that's the correct code that is needed to be able to display my data on a Flat List.  

Is this correct?  
.on('child_added', snap =>  {
      snap.key, 
      snap.val().Weight 
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getData` function currently doesn't return anything, so while the view may call `getData()` it gets nothing back from it.

But simply adding a `return` statement will not help, since the data is loaded asynchronously. In React you should instead put the data in the state of your component (by calling `setState()`) and then use it from there in your renderer.

In code:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.setState({ data: [] });
  this.getData();
}

getData(){
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/`)
    .orderByKey()
    .on('child_added', snap =>  {
      var data = this.state.data;
      data.push({ key: snap.key, weight: snap.val().Weight });
      this.setState({ data: data });
    }) 
}
```

So this:

- Initializes a `data` property in the state to an empty array.
- Adds each new item to `data` as it comes in from the database.

With this, you can render the array of data with:

```
renderRow = ({item}) => {
  return ( 
    <View style={[styles.card, styles.cardBorderTop]}> 
      <Text> 
        {item.key} 
      </Text> 
      <Text style={[styles.textRight]}>
        {item.Weight} 
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderRow} 
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This last bit may contain syntax errors, since I've never used `FlatList`. When in doubt, compare to the documentation of the latter [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist).

Comment: Thank you as always Frank. I had to change (item) to ({item}) and it all renders as intended. I have a follow up but related question. I created a new key which in my case is a date but the weight child for that key doesn't exist so now I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'data' of null. I know Firebase has a snap.exists function which I'm trying to implement with no luck and keep getting the error. I basically don't want the key to appear in my list if the weight child doesn't exist. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that the basic approach worked eric. Please make any edits that you needed to do to my answer, so that others can more easily copy/paste from it. :-)   I'll probably need to see the code for the new problem, so please post a new question (which also makes it more likely that someone else can help).

Comment: I added the ({item}) edit to the code Frank provided above and also placed componentWillMount inside of state to avoid the re-render issues I was having as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53532795/react-native-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this2-state-data-error-when-vi)