# React Native null is not an object (evaluating'_this2.state.data') error when visiting the screen a second time

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the following code to successfully render my Firebase database query.

```
class WeightHistoryScreen extends Component {
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setState({ data: [] });
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/`)
      .orderByKey()
      .on('child_added', snap =>  {
        var data = this.state.data;
        data.push({ key: snap.key, weight: snap.val().Weight });
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }) 
  }

renderRow = ({item}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.card, styles.cardBorder]}>
      <Text>
        {item.key}
      </Text>
      <Text style={[styles.textRight]}>
        {item.weight} LBS
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container]}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={this.renderRow} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

However I'm getting an error when visiting the screen a second time on the same session. See the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing your state in the wrong place, try to do it this way

```
class WeightHistoryScreen extends Component {
state={data:[]}
componentWillMount = () => {
    this.getData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code which should be fixed I have added comments on the code and updated the code as well.

- componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
- You can access state value in setState so no need to access it above
  //var data = this.state.data; No need for this
- Don't modify the data array directly it can introduce side effects. Use spread operator instead

Initialise the data array in constructor

```
    constructor(){
             this.state={
                data:[]
            }
          }

            //Remove setState from here


     componentWillMount = () => {
            this.setState({ data: [] });
            this.getData();
          }
        getData(){
                const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
                firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/data/`)
                  .orderByKey()
                  .on('child_added', snap =>  {
this.setState(prevState=>({data: [...prevState.data,{ key: snap.key, weight: snap.val().Weight }]}));
                    }) }
```